# Flask: flask.request.args.get replacing '+' with space in url

Tags: python, flask, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use a flask server for an api that takes image urls through the http get parameters.

I am using this [url example](http://pastebin.com/u0D38Ufu) which is very long (on pastebin) and contain's many `+`'s in the url. I have the following route set up in my flask server

```
@webapp.route('/example', methods=['GET'])
def process_example(): 
    imageurl = flask.request.args.get('imageurl', '')
    url = StringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(imageurl).read())
    ...
```

but the issue I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/aly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/Users/aly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/Users/aly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 597, in open_data
    data = base64.decodestring(data)
  File "/Users/aly/anaconda/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 321, in decodestring
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Upon further inspection (i.e. printing the imageurl that flask gets) it would appear that the `+` characters are being replaced by literal spaces which seems to be screwing things up.

Is there an option for the `flask.args.get` function that can handle this?

Answer (score 14):

You need to encode your query parameters correctly; in [URL query paramater encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type), spaces are encoded to `+`, while `+` itself is encoded to `%2B`.

Flask cannot be told to treat specific data differently; you cannot reliably detect what data was correctly encoded and what wasn't. You could extract the parameters from query string manually, however, by using `request.query_string`.

The *better* approach is to escape your parameters correctly (in JavaScript, use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), for example). The `+` character is not the only problematic character in a Base64-encoded value; the format also uses `/` and `=`, both of which carry meaning in a URL, which is why there is a [URL-safe variant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications).

In fact, it is probably the `=` character at the end of that `data:` URL that is missing, being the more direct cause of the *Incorrect padding* error message. If you added it back you'd next indeed have problems with all the `+` characters having been decoded to `' '`.

Comment: @Martijin_Pieters Hi, I am not actually inputting the url from a webpage I am directly calling `<server>:<port>/example?imageurl=<url>`. So I think this has to be done at the flask level. Would request.query_string then be appropriate?

Comment: @Aly: You are then still responsible for encoding the parameter. You need to call `<server>:<port>/example?imageurl=<encoded-url>`.